# No values in ComboBox ExtJs

Tags: javascript, mysql, combobox, extjs4

I am trying to implement combobox of extjs but im facing some problems. I have a html form that is divided into multiple tabs. The first tab has 3 dropdownlist that i have to populate from 3 different Mysql database tables. I wrote the back-end code and it is returning values i checked it in log but when i click on drop-down, it shows loading and nothing is there. I am fairly new with ExtJs. Here is my code:

First is model:

```
Ext.define('osFamilyModel', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [
                    //{name: "osFamily"},
                    {name: 'os_description'}
               ]
        });
```

Second comes store:

```
Ext.define('osFamilyStore', {
                extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
                model: 'osFamilyModel',
                proxy: {
                    type: "ajax",
                    url: "<lp:resourceURL id='fetchOsFamily'/>",
                    timeout: 120000
                }
            });
```

The ComboBox:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
            id : 'editVmOsFamily',
            width : fieldWidth,
            renderTo : 'vmOsFamilyFieldContainer',
            store : Ext.create('osFamilyStore'),
            queryMode : 'remote',
            valueField : 'os_description',
            displayField : 'os_description',
            baseCls : 'third_span'
        });
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: you have `osFamily` commented out in the model, and then are trying to use it as the `valueField` + `displayField`, is that right?

Comment: @AustinGreco thats typoerror. Sorry